# select rows without space postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to select all rows that have no space in subjcode column below you see all subjcode with or without spaces

```
subjcode    subjdesc
Z00 198     Introduction to Zoology
Z00 199     General Zoology
Z00198      Introduction to Zoology
```

I'm trying to select only those dont have space

```
subjcode    subjdesc
Z00198      Introduction to Zoology
```

I found this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168134/find-rows-in-which-the-column-doesnt-contain-a-space but when i run

```
select * from table
where subjcode ~'[\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202f\u205f\u3000]'
ORDER BY subjecode DESC;
```

it says

```
Unicode escape values cannot be used for code point values above 007F when the server 
encoding is not UTF8
```

I'm currently using postgresql v9.5 using pgadmin III if anyone is asking

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select * from table where subjcode not like '% %' ORDER BY subjecode DESC;
```

Maybe there are some gotchas, but my one minute test showed that it works. Might not be very performant on huge tables though.

Comment: You were faster. Just had exactly the same answer coming.

Comment: its blank apparently

Comment: Maybe this then? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168134/find-rows-in-which-the-column-doesnt-contain-a-space

Comment: I already tried that but its all resulting blank

Answer (score 1):

You could trust your collation to know what a space is:

```
WHERE subjcode !~ '[[:space:]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your database isn't using `UTF-8` encoding, so you can't use characters above `007F`.

Which also means you can't really have any such character in your data, so all you need to do is to remove those

```
where subjcode ~ '[\u0020\u00A0]'
```

But `\u0020` **is** a space character, so you probably want something like:

```
where subjcode ~ '[\u0009\u000A\u000D\u000C\u00A0]'
```